# Fail to upload iOS APNs Certificate on Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I can't upload my production APNs Certicate on Firebase. There was an error reading your certificate.

I can't find out the cause of this error.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should select only the certificate and don't select the private key . See this screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue before due to not proper "Certificate Signing Request". You may miss the Common name when you create a "Certificate Signing Request" or you may mentioned any other mails that didn't include in your xcode as developer Account.

Please try to put a common name and do the process again to create a new APN Certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you make some mistake's to create the certificate. Follow [this](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522) link to create certificate correctly and try.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I have faced this issue because I was exported 2 items Apple Development Push Services along with private key, and uploaded .p12 file to firebase. Then it said there was an error reading your certificate.

So the solution is don't export private key along with Apple Development Push Services item. Now generated .p12 file uploaded in Firebase. And the upload was successful.

Hope it will help to someone.